# A question regarding a class and it's methods

Tags: python

I am currently trying to write an ircbot and have gotten stuck. As you can see I define a method for the ircBot class, connect, which creates a socket object. I want to use this object in the sendCmd method, is this possible?

I have been looking around google and stackoverflow but have not been able to work out a solution(probably because I'm rather new to Python). Any hints appreciated!

```
import socket
import sys
import os

class ircBot:

    def sendCmd(self, cmd):
        SEND_TEXT_ON_OPEN_SOCKET

    def connect(self, server, port):

        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        c = s.connect_ex((server, port))

        if c == 111:
            print("Error: " + os.strerror(c))
            sys.exit(1)

            print("Making connection to " + server + "\n")
```

Regards,

David

Answer (score 3):

The trick is the first parameter to the methods, normally named `self` in Python. When you call the methods, this parameter is automatically passed.

It's the instance of the class -- so if you do `ircbot.sendCmd(cmd)`, `sendCmd` gets `ircbot` as `self`, and so it could use itself as `self.sendCmd` if you wanted.

You can add attributes to `self`, and it adds them to the instance -- this means that what `connect` does to `self`, `sendCmd` will see as well.

```
import socket
import sys
import os

class IrcBot: # You should consider doing 'class IrcBot(object):'
              # if you're on Python 2, so it's a new-style class
    def sendCmd(self, cmd):
        # use self.s here
        SEND_TEXT_ON_OPEN_SOCKET

    def connect(self, server, port):

        self.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        c = self.s.connect_ex((server, port))

        if c == 111: # is this the only return code that matters?
                     # I don't know, you might want to check for others
            print("Error: " + os.strerror(c))
            sys.exit(1)

            print("Making connection to " + server + "\n")

ircbot = IrcBot()
ircbot.connect('localhost', 6667)
ircbot.sendCmd('yourcmd')
```

Comment: +1 I found a better explanation of the `self` to be this: `classInstance.function(argument)` is the equivalent of `Class.function(classInstance, argument)`.

Comment: I'm not sure it helps to point out you can call methods on classes directly to people just learning Python / OOP, better to get a sense of the difference between a class and it's instance first.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign it to a variable which can be accessed outside of `connect`. Normally this is done by creating something called a member level variable:

```
class ircBot:

    def sendCmd(self, cmd):
        # SEND_TEXT_ON_OPEN_SOCKET
        s.doSomething()

    def connect(self, server, port):

        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        c = s.connect_ex((server, port))

        if c == 111:
            print("Error: " + os.strerror(c))
            # this should probably simply throw an exception. No need to take teh
            # whole system down on socket connection failure.
            sys.exit(1)
        self.s = s
        # I moved this up a level because you could never get to it in the 
        # if statement -- sys.exit leaves the application!
        print("Making connection to " + server + "\n")
```

Comment: A member level variable? Not an instance variable, or instance attribute? I think that's a .net term, haven't really heard it used in Python?

Answer (score 0):

```
import socket
import sys
import os

class ircBot:

    def sendCmd(self, cmd):
        if self.s is None:
           raise "Not connected to a server"
        self.s.send(cmd)

    def connect(self, server, port):

        self.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        c = self.s.connect_ex((server, port))

        if c == 111:
            print("Error: " + os.strerror(c))
            sys.exit(1)

            print("Making connection to " + server + "\n")
```